# Splitting large html file in several files

Tags: jquery, html, excel, import, datatables

I want to preface the following by saying that I am pretty novice at html coding.

I am currently building a relatively large database (2000 entries) in excel and I want to make that database available on my website. What I started doing is converting the excel data to html data, and then using the DataTables jQuery plugin to convert it into a nice searchable html table. Here is what my code looks like:

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.13/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.4/dt-1.10.13/fh-3.1.2/datatables.min.js"></script>

<style>
  some style options
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#booklist').dataTable({
    });
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="booklist" class="display">
 Table data here
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am still updating periodically the database, and having to copy and paste the new table data in the document every time is annoying, especially since it represents around 10000 lines.

I was wondering if there is a way to keep the table data in a separate file, say `b.html`, and importing it in such a way as it would be interpreted the same way as simply pasting the content of it directly where "Table data here" appears in my original code.

I tried using jQuery `.load()` function, but could not get it to work. Is it problematic that I am using CSS formatting?

Let me know what you think is the best solution to my problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Using `.load()` and then calling the `.dataTable()` function from within the `.load()` method's complete callback should be OK. What happened when you "could not get it to work"? Did the data load but not get formatted, or not load at all, or did you get an error in the browser's console, or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a way to keep the table data in a separate file, say b.html, and importing it in such a way as it would be interpreted the same way as simply pasting the content of it directly where "Table data here" appears in my original code.

You definitely have the right idea. You can make an HTTP request for HTML (or data of any kind really). There are multiple ways to do this but an easy way is to use jQuery's `$(...).load('/...')` function as you're doing now.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "test.html" );
```

where `result` is the id of the div you want to populate with the value of `test.html`

This will make a request for `test.html` and put in the document in a div with the id `result`.

Under the hood, `$(...).load()` sends a request asynchronously and updates the element when the request completes. In addition to the URL, you should also provide a callback to run code after the load call has been finishes. Therefore, we can call `DataTable()` *after* the html loads.

```js
// this URL would be an http://... in actual use
// table taken from w3schools
let url = "data:text/html,%3Ctable%20id%3D%22my-table%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3ECompany%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3EContact%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3ECountry%3C%2Fth%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EAlfreds%20Futterkiste%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EMaria%20Anders%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EGermany%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3ECentro%20comercial%20Moctezuma%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EFrancisco%20Chang%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EMexico%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EErnst%20Handel%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3ERoland%20Mendel%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EAustria%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EIsland%20Trading%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EHelen%20Bennett%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EUK%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3ELaughing%20Bacchus%20Winecellars%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EYoshi%20Tannamuri%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3ECanada%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EMagazzini%20Alimentari%20Riuniti%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EGiovanni%20Rovelli%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EItaly%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%3C%2Ftable%3E";

// need to give `load` a callback so we can run code *after* the HTML loads
$('#result').load(url, function () {
  $('#my-table').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>result get populated below:</div>
  <div id="result">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> Let me know what you think is the best solution to my problem.

If you have a giant spreadsheet, you could probably save that as a CSV and use [a CSV parser](http://papaparse.com/) to transform each row in the table to a row in html. This involves:

1. an ajax request with jquery (or `fetch`) for the data as CSV
2. parsing it into arrays
3. transforming that to rows of HTML and adding them to the document
4. then finally calling `DataTables()`

But if your database is relatively large, then you should try going for dynamic pagination which is hard without server code (nodejs, php, java etc).

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it working at last thanks to your help. I think part of the problem I had was that I couldn't get `.load()` to work at all, and it ended up being because I was using chrome. Somehow I only get a blank page as if nothing got imported. It works just fine on Firefox. Anybody knows what's up with that?

Comment: open the developer console (F12) in chrome and let me know if there are any errors

Comment: Here is the error message for chrome. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///[...]/test.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.` Not sure what it means though.

Comment: @ZetaOrionis i think you're getting this error because you're opening the files directly. It should work if you open it using a web server. If you have npm installed you can `npm install -g http-server` then run `http-server` from the root of your project folder. Then you should be able to go to `http://localhost:8080/` and see your page

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<link>` element with `rel` attribute set to `import`, get data using `.import` property of `link` element, which returns a `document`

```
<link rel="import" type="text/html" href="b.html" />
```

```html
<head>
<link id="data" 
      rel="import" 
      type="text/html" 
      href='data:text/html,{"abc":123, "def":[4,5,6]}' />
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    const data = document.getElementById("data");
    let entries = JSON.parse(data.import.body.textContent);

    console.log(entries);
    /*
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#booklist').dataTable({
        // populate `.dataTable()` with selected `entries`
      })
    });
    */

  </script>
</body>
```